# Callback function problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-maps, callback

Here I have a function calculateDistance which must return me a distance between two places and time so I write:

```
 function calculateDistances(start,stop) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [start],
      destinations: [stop],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}
  function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;


    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
       var xxx= "";
        xxx += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
            + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
            + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
     return xxx;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

after that I write a code to implement this function into my js code:

```
//Start function for calculate distance
        var start = document.getElementById("from").value;
        var stop = place.formatted_address;
        contentStr += '<p>'+ calculateDistances(start,stop); + '</p>';

        //I open rendered HTML in jquery dialog when user click on marker
        $(contentStr).dialog({
          modal:true
      });
```

I just get as HTML: undefined and in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of null`

How I can solve this problem?
FULL CODE: http://jsbin.com/EVEWOta/96/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DirectionsService is asynchronous. You can't "return" the results from the callback function.  You have to use the results when they are returned by the server (in the callback function).  Not tested:

```
 function calculateDistances(start,stop) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [start],
      destinations: [stop],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}
  function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    var xxx= "";

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

        xxx += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
            + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
            + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
      }
      var contentStr += '<p>'+ xxx + '</p>';
    }    
    //I open rendered HTML in jquery dialog when user click on marker
    $(contentStr).dialog({
      modal:true
    });
  }
}

//Start function for calculate distance
var start = document.getElementById("from").value;
var stop = place.formatted_address;
calculateDistances(start,stop);
```

Comment: thanks but dont work... I will flag this answer as good so thanks again but its not a solution for my problem

Comment: When you say "dont work", what do you mean?  The code wasn't tested, there might be syntax errors. If it is something else, then I still don't understand your question.  Maybe you can provide more details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying when I open dialog to show me a distance between startPoint and opened Location on click on marker... how I can do that in my example: http://jsbin.com/EVEWOta/96/edit